# Concentration of measure for uniform distribution on Stiefel manifolds

Tags: pr.probability, haar-measure

This is my first post on MO, so I hope the question is suitable. I am looking at the uniform distribution on the Stiefel manifold, but more specifically, at the uniform distribution on the corresponding space of idempotent projection matrices. It is known that the expectation of such a projection matrix (of rank say $p$) is $E[P]=\frac{p}{n}I_n$,  where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix, and $P$ is uniformly distributed over the set of all idempotent (symmetric) matrices of rank $p$, and uniformly distributed is related to orthogonal invariance.

My question is, what type of concentration inequalities is known for such a distribution? Do we know if $P$ concentrates around its mean (this may depend on $p$?)? Do we know of a way to approximate $P$ by independent variables? Essentially, I have been looking for what we know about $P$.

Thank you!

Comment: This is directly related to concentration on Grassmannian manifolds, as an orthogonal projection is given by its image (a $p$-dimensional subspace, by definition an element of $G(p,n)$). For example, if $p=1$ or $p=n-1$, up to a double cover you can use the well-known concentration on the round sphere $S^{n-1}$. I guess that the keywords "Grassmannian" and "concentration" should get you what you want (and I indeed expect strong concentration to occur).

Comment: However, note that there is no way the concentration occurs near the mean, as the mean is far from the support of your measure: $E[P]$ has rank $n$, not $p$. Think of the uniform measure on the unit sphere: the mean is at the center, which is not on the sphere; but there still is concentration, in the sense that a small neighborhood of any equator sphere of codimension $1$ contains almost all the mass.

Comment: Thank you for the discussion. The difference in rank did make me wonder whether or not there is concentration. I guess the important part will be to get some more quantitative bounds. Thank you also for the keywords, as I had been searching on the Stiefel manifold and concentration side!